# problems with sticky navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am facing problems with sticky navbar on my website.

I used the code of [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_sticky) for this navbar. The problem is that when page is loading, navigation sticky effect appears, when page is fully loaded, the navigation goes to the top of page.

[Link to my website](http://novostroyka.shahar.uz/developer/FDG/)

Here is how nav menu looks like:
[image: Nav]

```
CSS:

      .sticky {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .sticky + .content {
      padding-top: 60px;
    }




    <script>
    window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
    
    var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
    var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
    
    function myFunction() {
      if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
      } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: why do you use position:fixed for a sticky navbar instead of position:sticky ? Javascript is not needed for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
#navbar {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your script inside a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  window.onscroll = function () { myFunction() };

  var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
  var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

  function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
      navbar.classList.add("sticky")
    } else {
      navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
  }
})
```

Also, you can replace `function() {myFunction()}` with just `myFunction`